# It's possible to make the Panorama control on WP7 non-circularly?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0, panorama-control

I'm using a Panorama control on a WP7 design, and I want to know if there's some way to deactivate the circular (or round) navigation on it?

Basically what I would is to end the horizontal scrolling to right on the last item and vice-versa.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786439/best-way-to-implement-a-wizard-style-ui-in-wp7

Answer (score 4):

Even if it was possible, such app would most likely get rejected at Marketplace review.

The strength of a system lies in uniformity. Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Users expect panoramas to loop.

Comment: You could use the Panorama control and make a user control derived from it, but I'm with Agent_L.  Users expect it to work a certain way, and overriding their expectations is a good way to frustrate users.  As for Marketplace, I'm not sure it would get rejected, but I would not encourage doing it.

Comment: The application was not meant to be on the Marketplace or even face final users, it was a concept design (or prototype) and I needed to have that specific interaction.